# Convergent series multiplied by $n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

this one should be really simple...

Let $\mathbb a_n$ be a sequence of strictly positive real numbers such that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}a_n$ is finite, i.e., the limit $\lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^ka_n$ exists.

Then $a_n$ has to converge to zero, pretty quickly so. -- That much I do remember.

Does it follow that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot n=0$ has to hold?

Here is what I do (seem to) remember:

If the limit exists, then $a_n$ has to converge to zero, ``quicker'' than $1/n$,
thus(???), there has to exist some $\epsilon>0$ such that $a_n$ goes to zero as fast as  $(1/n)^{1+\epsilon}$.

--- But is this true?

If this is in fact true, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\cdot n = 0$ does hold.

Comment: $$a_n = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{n} &, n \text{ is a square}\\ \frac{1}{2^n} &, n\text{ is not a square} \end{cases}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer, I believe this merits being made into an answer.

Comment: The claim is true **if** the series's sequence $\;\{a_n\}\;$ is monotonically convergent to zero...

Comment: Thanks Daniel, exactly what I feared is true.

Comment: @DonAntonio does monotonicity have to be strict, i.e., $a_{n+1}<a_n$ for all but finitely many $n$ or is $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$ sufficient?

Comment: @Jorgan, I believe one can work it out both ways, if necessary by taking a subsequence that is strictly monotone (and it **must** exist such a subsequence as the sequence converges to zero).

Answer (score 7):

We have a counterexample by

$$a_n = \begin{cases}\frac{1}{n} &, n \text{ is a square}\\ \frac{1}{2^n} &, n\text{ is not a square}. \end{cases}$$

This sequence has $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} na_n = 1$, and

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k^2}} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} < \infty.$$

If we took a sparser sequence of special values, say $a_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for $n$ a cube, we could also have $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} na_n = +\infty$.

However, if the sequence $a_n$ is monotonic, then $na_n \to 0$ follows.

By the Cauchy condensation test, if $a_n$ is monotonic,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n < \infty \iff \sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^ka_{2^k} < \infty.$$

Since the series on the left converges by assumption, so does the right, and that implies that $\lim_{k\to\infty} 2^ka_{2^k} = 0$. But then for $2^k \leqslant n < 2^{k+1}$ we have

$$0 \leqslant n a_n \leqslant 2^{k+1}a_n \leqslant 2^{k+1}a_{2^k} = 2(2^ka_{2^k}),$$

and the right hand side converges to $0$. By squeezing, so does $na_n$.

Comment: Pardon my idiocy. But why does $\sum a_n$ converge?

Comment: We take a convergent series, $\sum \frac{1}{2^n}$, and replace some terms with the terms of another convergent series, $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$, thus the overall sum is $< \sum \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: How do you prove the last bit?
If $a_n$ is (strictly) decreasing, then... ?

Comment: Your answer does answer my question. Thanks for that.
But, I have a bit of wriggle room for my series $a_n$.
So I could arrange that $a_n$ is decreasing. How does on prove your last statement?

Comment: It's a consequence of the Cauchy condensation test, @Jorgan, let me edit.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot!